# IO exception is not handle

Tags: java, android

I have an issue in my Android app saying "Unhandled IOException: java.io.exception" when I'm trying to getBitmap from URI. below is the code.

I do not want to catch all exception using a catch (exception e) as it's too wide.

```
private void getBitmapFromURI(Uri uri) {
        try {
            mSnapShot = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);

            int PreviewSizeWidth = CameraApplication.Instance().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.FilterPreviewWidth);
            int PreviewSizeHeight = CameraApplication.Instance().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.FilterPreviewHeight);
            mPreviewBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mSnapShot, PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight, false);
            FiltersPreview();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "File not found");
            finish();
        }
    }
```

any idea how to catch exception in case getbitmap not working ?

thx

Comment: Uhm you add a catch for IOException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
try {
        mSnapShot = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);

        int PreviewSizeWidth = CameraApplication.Instance().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.FilterPreviewWidth);
        int PreviewSizeHeight = CameraApplication.Instance().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.FilterPreviewHeight);
        mPreviewBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mSnapShot, PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight, false);
        FiltersPreview();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "File not found");
        finish();
    }catch(IOException e){
          //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the multi catch and make sure to log your exception in logcat. Something like this.

```
    catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also catch the `IOException`

```
private void getBitmapFromURI(Uri uri) {
    try {
        mSnapShot = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);

        int PreviewSizeWidth = CameraApplication.Instance().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.FilterPreviewWidth);
        int PreviewSizeHeight = CameraApplication.Instance().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.FilterPreviewHeight);
        mPreviewBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mSnapShot, PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight, false);
        FiltersPreview();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "File not found");
        finish();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "IO error");
        finish();
    }

}
```

or you have to change you method signature to

```
private void getBitmapFromURI(Uri uri) throws IOException
```

and handle this on an other place.